# IllegalStateException / NullPointerException при работе с AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Есть `AlertDialog` с `AutoCompleteTextView`. Не могу понять, почему у меня не инициализируется `autoCompleteTextView`.

> AutoCompleteTextView в Layout:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/add_food_name_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorLink="?attr/colorButtonNormal"
    tools:text="@string/enter_good" />
```

> Обработчик входа в Layout:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    View addFoodView;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
    final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
            "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
    };

public void onClickAddFoodButton(View view) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext());
    addFoodView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_food_layout, null);
    alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(addFoodView);
    alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.add_food_name_text);
    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(autoCompleteTextView));
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES));
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
}
```

> Log:

```
05-28 10:59:51.145 23806-23806/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch I/AppActivity: null
05-28 10:59:51.145 23806-23806/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-28 10:59:51.145 23806-23806/ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch, PID: 23806
                                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.AppActivity.onClickAddFoodButton(AppActivity.java:236)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756) 
                                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

C первой же строчки видно, что `autoCompleteView = null`. Но я же его инициализирую... Подскажите, как быть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь найти элемент во `View` основного слоя, вам необходимо искать так:

```
autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) addFoodView.findViewById(R.id.add_food_name_text);
```